# Sort отказывается сортировать по численному значению

Tags: linux

Добрый день. Возникла неожиданная проблема с самым обычным **sort**'ом: выполняю скрипт, передаю его конвеером sort'у с ключом **-n**, скрипт возвращает строку, в которой первое поле (отделенное пробелом) являет собой битрейт, целое число, 2-3 цифры. Но sort всегда сортирует как строку, то есть битрейт 96 оказывается ниже 320 при ascendind-сортировке.

Пробовал указывать ключи:

```
-n
--numeric-sort
-g
```

и другие вовсе непонятные, подсказанные ИПС. Ничего не работает. Сортирует всегда как строку. Почему?

Аутентичный пример передаваемых на вход строк:

```
224 kbps: ./Рабфак - Менты/mp3
128 kbps: ./daneliya - mimino.mp3
96 kbps: ./Velvet Underground - White light.mp3
320 kbps: ./Nazareth - Telegram.mp3
```

В выходе идет так: 128, 224, 320, 96.

Команда:

```
mp3_bitrate.sh -d | sort -n
```

Comment: Приведите пример сортируемых строк

Comment: так надо сортировать "по-человечески", т.е. `sort -h`

Comment: 320 kbps: ./Roy_Orbison_-_Unchained_melody.mp3, 96 kbps: ./ Velvet_Underground_-_White_light.mp3 === строка с битрейтом 96 оказывается в возрастающем списке ПОСЛЕ строки с 320

Comment: Увы! Опция -h привела к тому же результату.

Comment: `-h` правильно сортирует не только простые числа, но и 10K и 1M, я подумал у вас из-за этого и проблема. И у меня обе опции сортируют правильно. Вставьте ваши строки в вопрос так, как они у вас подаются на вход. Т.е. добавьте в вопрос все, что требуется для воспроизведения у себя неправильного поведения. И, на всякий случай, `sort --version` и используемую ось. И попробуйте вставить эти две строки в файл и сделать `cat your_file | sort -n` - результат будет тем же самым?

Comment: Попробовал ваш вариант. Порядок следования строк в файле: 320, 96, 160. Порядок после сортировки: 160, 320, 96.

Comment: ок, а теперь сделайте `mp3_bitrate.sh -d > out.log`, а затем `cat out.log | sort -n`, результат будет тем же самым? и приведенный пример совпадает с содержимым полученного файла? Вы версию cat'a покажите и систему, может в этой версии был такой баг?

Comment: Все совпадает, и содержимое и результат.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31867/discussion-between-bopoh-and-jacen-kaedus).

Comment: Покажите вывод `sort --version`

Answer (score 2):

Я наконец-то заставил работать так, как надо, использовав ключ **-V** *(natural sort of (version) numbers within text)*.
Конечная команда, хоть и понятно, выглядела так:

```
mp3_bitrate.sh -d | sort -V
```

Тем не менее, по-прежнему остается неясным, почему обычные-то -n, -h и т.д. ключи не работали. Как говорится - то ли баг, то ли фича...

Comment: а можете показать вывод `mp3_bitrate.sh -d | sort -n --debug`? Должно вывести используемую локаль и подчеркнуть ключ, по которому идет сортировка.

Answer (score 0):

`sort` пытается отсортировать строки по совокупности полей. Для сортировки только по одному полю используйте следующую комбинацию ключей:

```
sort -t " " -k 1n
```

Здесь `-t " "` - установить разделитель полей (пробел),
`-b`- игнорировать пробелы в начале строки (если они у вас есть),
`-k 1n` - сортировать только по первому полю, сравнивая значения как числа.
Если обратный порядок сортировки надо - добавьте ключ `r`: `-k 1nr`

Comment: проблема не в этом, sort прекрасно сортирует если просто указать `sort -n` или `sort -h`, в данном случае он почему-то сортирует числа как строки, возможно, у автора команда просто коряво написана

Comment: команду сейчас тоже приведу оригинальную, без купюр. хотя там нечего искажать

Comment: и ответ выглядит логичным и обещающим, но увы, тоже не помогает.

Comment: Создал файл test со следующим содержимым:
224 kbps: ./Рабфак - Менты/mp3
128 kbps: ./daneliya - mimino.mp3
96 kbps: ./Velvet Underground - White light.mp3
320 kbps: ./Nazareth - Telegram.mp3
Выполняю так: `cat test | sort -n`
Результат:
96 kbps: ./Velvet Underground - White light.mp3
128 kbps: ./daneliya - mimino.mp3
224 kbps: ./Рабфак - Менты/mp3
320 kbps: ./Nazareth - Telegram.mp3

Comment: Загадочно. Возможно, в моем дистрибутиве какой-то бажный сорт?

Comment: @JacenKaedus, учитывая «своеобразность» используемого вами дистрибутива (я так понимаю, что это до сих пор *tiny core linux*), вполне возможно, что описанная проблема относится **не только** к программе `sort`.